# How can I use native macOS windows in ZStack form in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want be able to use macOS native windows like we can use views in SwiftUI, with this condition that the first window has `isMovableByWindowBackground = false` and the second one has `isMovableByWindowBackground = true` and with moving the movable window the unmovable window following the movable one.

The current code make the all window movable, which is not my goal, I want just the red view be movable, and with movement of this red view the yellow window is following the red window.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
 
        VStack {
            
            Button("show window") {
                
                ZStack {
                    myView()
                    myView2()
                }
                .openInWindow(sender: nil)

            }
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)

    }
    
    func myView() -> some View {
        return Color.yellow.frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
    
    func myView2() -> some View {
        return Color.red.frame(width: 25, height: 25).overlay(Image(systemName: "arrow.up.and.down.and.arrow.left.and.right"))
    }
    
}


extension View {
    @discardableResult
    func openInWindow(sender: Any?) -> NSWindow {
        let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: self)
        let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: controller)
        window.contentViewController = controller
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender)
        window.titleVisibility = .hidden
        window.toolbar = nil
        window.styleMask = .fullSizeContentView
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        return window
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In the same way as I answered, add yellow window as a child of red window, but in this case not above, but below it, and set isMovableByWindowBackground for each one as needed.

Comment: You used `if let parent = NSApp.mainWindow` in last answer, but the parent in current question is a SwiftUI view, I tried to use `if let parent = myView2().openInWindow(sender: nil)` but xcode make error of: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSWindow'`

Comment: Then it is not clear from description whether you want two windows (one yellow, one red, when yellow one dragged with dragging red one) or two views in one window (where window is draggable only by red view).

Comment: @Asperi: I just tried your advice and this time the codes build with no issue, the problem was there that I was using non optional NSWindow as you can see in the error in comment, after paying attention a little more, all worked like butter as you said in comment! thanks.